# pgfgantt errors when compiling in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, pgfgantt

I have looked for a solution for some time but not having found any similar case, I'll post it here.

I'm using the latex package `pgfgantt` to create some gantt charts. It works very well in my pc (both Linux and Windows). But I use overleaf to share my documents and it never compiles there with several errors. The solution I've been using for now is to generate static images for the gantts and import then import them as images but it's a tedious task I do not feel like doing everytime I edit the gantts.

Not sure if it's valid to post links to code, here is a small example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/vctdfktthsvv

From among the many errors I get, it appears their version doesn't like some of the options for the ganttchart (`expand chart=\textwidth` and `time slot unit=month`).

I'm guessing the problem is a different version of `pgfgantt`?

Is there a way to workaround it in a smarter way than what I've been doing? or, even better, to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Franco

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your version of `pgfgantt` is more recent than Overleaf's (which is TeXLive 2017, I think). Just upload your copy of `pgfgantt.sty` to Overleaf and it will work.

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik for such a quick response! No idea it was possible to just override the version of any given package putting it just next to the document. It took a couple of minutes of google+pc researching to find the actual location of miktex packages in my system. For anyone interested... it was here: %APPDATA%\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pgfgantt\pgfgantt.sty How do I marked the question as answered if there's only a comment?

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Yes, when TeX looks for a file it first looks the current folder. If the file is not there, then it looks for the one in the TeX distribution tree. To look for the location of a package file you can always check the log file, which will contain the full path of the loaded file. Or, if your a command-line person, you can use `kpsewhich pgfgantt.sty`. Another option is to download the package files from CTAN.